QML Create a component in a different file
I'm dealing with a little problem: I've 3 files: main.qml, actions.qml and edit.qml. The idea is that in edit I should do something, and that would create a row in an scroll in actions after pressing a button(Kind of like a history). A minimal example looks like this:
main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Item {
    id: main
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    focus: true

    Rectangle {
        radius: 5
        border.color: "black"
        opacity: 0.6
        anchors.fill: acts
        color: "steelblue"
        visible: acts.visible
    }

    Actions {
        id: acts
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 50
        width: parent.width * 0.3
        visible: true
    }

    Rectangle {
        radius: 5
        border.color: "black"
        opacity: 0.6
        anchors.fill: edit
        color: "lightcoral"
        visible: edit.visible
    }

    Edit {
        id: edit
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 200
        width: parent.width * 0.3
        height: 100
        visible: true
    }
}

Actions.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Item {
    ScrollView {
            id: scrollarea
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            anchors.top: parent.top
            Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height * 0.9

            ColumnLayout {
                id: actions
                objectName: "actions"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
        }
}

Edit.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Item {
    Button {
            text: "Press me"
            onClicked: {
                var component;
                var sprite;
                component = Qt.createComponent("action.qml");
                sprite = component.createObject(actions, {"objectName": "ActionRow"});
            }
        }
}

action.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

RowLayout {
    id: act
    spacing: parent.width * 0.02
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    
    RadioButton {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 10
    }

    
    Button {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 20
        text: "X"
        onClicked: {
            act.destroy()
        }
    }

    
    Label {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 300
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat"
    }
}

If I put those 3 files together it works correctly, but if I try to separate it then it causes reference errors(And I prefer to separate it to make it easier to edit in the future), Is it possible to do what I'm trying to make? Just for a little extra context, I'm using PyQt5 in the background to put all this together.

You didn't specify, but I assume the error you're getting is from the fact that Edit.qml is referencing actions which is the ColumnLayout defined in Actions.qml, and thus not accessible here.
The most direct way to fix that is to use signals. Move functions relating to actions into Actions.qml, and nothing else needs to know what an action is.

main.qml

Item {
    Actions {
        id: acts
    }

    Edit {
        onEditClicked() {
            acts.addAction();
        }
    }
}


Edit.qml

Item {
    signal editClicked()

    Button {
        onClicked: editClicked();
    }
}


Actions.qml

Item {
    function addItem() {
        var component;
        var sprite;
        component = Qt.createComponent("action.qml");
        sprite = component.createObject(actions, {"objectName": "ActionRow"});
    }

    ScrollView {
        ColumnLayout {
            id: actions
        }
    }
}

The other change I would recommend is to avoid manually creating objects the way you're doing it. (It's perfectly legitimate code, but much harder to maintain.) A ListView (or Repeater) will automatically generate Items represented by a model. (The simplest type of model is just a count of the number of items you want.) So you could change your Actions.qml to look like this:
Item {
    property int numActions: 0

    function addItem() {
        numActions++;
    }

    ListView {
        model: numActions
        delegate: Action { }
    }
}


Yes, perfect, this was the way, and sorry about not specifying where the error came from, maybe I wrote too fast the issue. Also, thanks for the recommendation, will check if it works for what I had planned!
